# GWT-508 compliant- How to set HTML tags

Tags: java, html, gwt, celltable, section508

I am in the process of making my GWT page 508 compliant and I need to add some additional information on the sort buttons in my cellTable for the screen reader to pick up. Basically I need to know how to set the Label HTML tag from the cellTable.

I know how to use the `setTitle()` and `setAlt()` methods but I can't seem to find an easy way to set the `Label` for buttons. I understand screen readers can optionally view Title tags but that is not what I want to have to do.

I cant seem to find anyone else out there with this problem, how has this not come up more?

Answer (score 1):

There's a TODO in the code actually: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.6.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DefaultHeaderOrFooterBuilder.java

```
// TODO: Figure out aria-label and translation of label text
```

and there doesn't seem to be any hack/hook to add it.

So the only solution seems to be to fork/patch GWT (and if possible contribute the patch upstream).

BTW, the sort icons are not buttons, just indicators. The whole table header responds to click, so the `aria-label` has to be added to the `<th>` element.

(well, actually, there seems to be a workaround: walk the table DOM looking for the appropriate `<th>` element and add the `aria-label` attribute using `Roles.getButtonRole().`[`setAriaLabelProperty()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/aria/client/Role.html#setAriaLabelProperty%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element,%20java.lang.String%29); but fixing GWT would be less fragile, much better in the long run and good for everyone)

Comment: thanks for your response! This seems to be a little over my head though, would a simple sortbutton.setHTML("<LABEL> My sort</LABEL>") call work?